# Is there an operation that gives different output for equal inputs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there an operation that gives different output for equal inputs?

Example:
$\frac{1}{2}$ = $\frac{2}{4}$, $f$ is an operation such that $f(\frac{1}{2}) \neq f(\frac{2}{4})$.

Is there something like that in mathematics?

Comment: Not really, but there isn't anything like that in natural language either. You don't say that Santa's blue cow isn't equal to Santa's blue cow, you say that that two different cows have the property of being a blue cow of Santa's, and perhaps avoid using functional notation and equal sign altogether.

Comment: What notation should I use? @SassatelliGiulio

Comment: Perhaps binary relations? I don't know what you're doing.

Comment: By definition, no.  Functions (*and operations are a specific class of functions*) are specifically required to be *well defined*, meaning that when applied to the same input (*regardless of presentation*) the output remains the same.  Perhaps though you want to emphasize how $\frac{1}{2}$ is "not the same" as $\frac{2}{4}$.  Well, ordinarily we do want these to be the same.  You could however treat them as different if you are careful about it and are willing to emphasize and explain this to the reader.

Comment: It would probably be easiest though to just work with different objects that are more obviously distinct... talking about functions that take multiple inputs and writing these as $f(1,2)$ and $f(2,4)$ which clearly don't need to be equal.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that the function [$\operatorname{atan2}(y,x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) was introduced to provide more nuanced results than $\arctan\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)$, by effectively incorporating "quadrant detection" using signs. For example, we have $\operatorname{atan2}(1,2)=\operatorname{atan2}(-1,-2)-\pi$, even though $\arctan\left(\dfrac12\right)=\arctan\left(\dfrac{-1}{-2}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

That is impossible because by very definition, $a =b \implies f(a)=f(b)$. Therefore $f(a)\neq f(b) \implies a \neq b$.

Also by the general consensus around the meaning of equality, if $a=b$, then a and b are indistinguishable.